# Masm Program Not Working.(Using Win32 API - CreateFile)

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

This simple MASM program keeps crashing.

I'm using the Win32 API

The `CreateFile` function is not working and is making my app crash.

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 

.data 
filename byte "dummy.txt", 0

.code 
main PROC

    INVOKE CreateFile,
                filename,
                GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                NULL,
                CREATE_NEW,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL

    invoke ExitProcess,NULL
main ENDP
END main
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `CreateFile` is the *address of* the filename, not the first couple of characters of the filename. So you need to place an `ADDR` operator before `filename` in your `invoke`:

```
INVOKE CreateFile,
            ADDR filename,  
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            CREATE_NEW,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
```